# Create buffer and immediately hide it?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for a way to create a buffer and immediately hide it. It is a buffer for technical information, not interesting to the user, and it is used with `shell-command` to process the output.

`kill-buffer` - is not what I need, because I need that buffer to be live.

`delete-window` - doesn't do it either because there's no way to make sure how exactly the buffer will open (it may create a new window or may take over another window).

It doesn't help if I create the buffer before supplying it to `shell-command` Regardless of whether it existed before, it will bring it to front and, if there was only one window at the time it did it, it will create an additional window, but if there were more windows, then it basically does something random. Some times it will create a new window... other times it won't.

EDIT:

The example below illustrates the problem:

```
(defun haxe-start-waiting-server (&optional compiler host port)
  "Starts Haxe `haxe-compiler' on `haxe-server-host':`haxe-server-port'
with \"--wait\" for the future requests made by autocompletion
or flymake.
This function is bound to \\[haxe-start-waiting-server]"
  (interactive
   (let ((compiler-i
          (read-string "Haxe compiler: "
                       haxe-compiler t haxe-compiler))
         (host-i
          (read-string "Haxe server host: "
                       haxe-server-host t haxe-server-host))
         (port-i
          (read-number "Haxe server port: " haxe-server-port)))
     (list compiler-i host-i port-i)))
  (unless (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
    (unless compiler (setq compiler haxe-compiler))
    (unless host (setq compiler haxe-server-host))
    (unless port (setq compiler haxe-server-port)))
  (save-excursion
    (let ((new-buffer
           (get-buffer-create
            (generate-new-buffer-name
             " *haxe-waiting-server*"))))
      (async-shell-command
       (concat compiler " --wait "
               host ":" (number-to-string port))
       new-buffer)
      (bury-buffer new-buffer))))
```

Comment: How are you creating the buffer? A buffer created with `get-buffer-create` is not even displayed so there is no need to hide it

Comment: From `async-shell-command` documentation: `In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling \`start-process'
directly [...]`. You may want to check `async-shell-command` code and use `start-process` instead

Comment: I will add my comment as answer in case you want to accept it. About hiding a visible buffer, doesn't `bury-buffer` work for you?

Comment: `bury-buffer` doc says: If BUFFER-OR-NAME is nil or omitted, bury the current buffer and _remove it from the selected window_ if it is displayed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want everything to happen in the background, you may need `save-window-excursion` instead of `save-excursion`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html):

> Buffers that are ephemeral and generally uninteresting to the user
>   have names starting with a space, so that the list-buffers and
>   buffer-menu commands don't mention them (but if such a buffer visits a
>   file, it is mentioned). A name starting with space also initially
>   disables recording undo information; see Undo.

Comment: @wvxvw: If it hurts, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

For finer control on buffer behavior, you might want to use `start-process` instead of `async-shell-command`. From its documentation:

> In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling `start-process'
>   directly, since it offers more control and does not impose the use of
>   a shell (with its need to quote arguments).